# ConfigParser giving error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, configparser

I am using config parser  to read an item **tasks or Tasks** from an INI file. The problem with the code is, it is checking for the case of Item. but in my case the item can be having case.
config file:

```
[tasks]
;Order of the tasks is important
Create_ElasticIP=yes
Create_VPC=yes
Create_InternetGateway=yes
Attach_InternetGateway=yes
Create_Subnet_Public=yes
Create_Subnet_Private=yes
Create_Subnet_Private1=yes
Common_Beanstalk_RDS=no
Create_NATGateway=yes
Create_SecurityGroup_Public=no
Create_SecurityGroup_Private=no
Create_ElasticBeanstalk=yes
UploadVersion_ElasticBeanstalk=no
Create_S3Bucket=no
Create_SQS=no
Create_DynamoDBTable=no
Create_RDS_DBInstance=yes

[Create_ElasticIP]
input=Create_ElasticIP.json
method=Create_ElasticIP
```

below is the code

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.optionxform = str
config.read(Ini_File)        
items=config.items('Tasks')
```

It is showing below error

> raise NoSectionError(section) configparser.NoSectionError: No section:
>   'Tasks'

Comment: you have to share with us the content of your `Ini_File`. Based on the error, it looks like there is no `[Tasks]` section in your file

Comment: We can;t help you without having the `ini` file....

Comment: added the ini file

Comment: Your section name is capitalized in the code, but not in the ini file. I.e. `Tasks` vs `tasks`.

Comment: As @favoretti mentioned, if you'll use `tasks` as section, your code should be working

Comment: Thanks @Moinuddin Quadri